# How do programs create virtual hardware?

Tags: hardware, virtual, driver

I've seen programs like magicdisc create virtual cd drives and mount them on the machine. How do these programs trick the operating system into thinking there is a new hardware device attached to it?

I imagine I would have to write a driver for the virtual hardware, and I am comfortable in C so that doesn't sound terrible, but how do I make the OS think there is a piece of hardware attached to it that isn't?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58950/How-to-develop-a-virtual-disk-for-Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the operating system has different layers and libraries, at some point there is a library that sits between something above it and the actual hardware, you fake it there, if there is some sort of read sector call, you pretend to read a sector using that sector address, read it from a file, whatever.  Each operating system (windows, linux, etc) may do things a different way.

Comment: another way to say it is that there are drivers that on the bottom side talk to hardware on the top side (at some layer) have a generic interface so that for example all video drivers can plug into an operating system or all sound card drivers, etc.  You find that generic layer or one of the generic layers that you want to start from and implement the virtual hardware under that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are familiar with C as application level, which is above OS.
The virtual driver is a piece a software, but need to write in proper locations the settings: Registry at Windows, some config file at some Linux. You need to handle OS level calls and callbacks at Kernel level. Than you will desire the software too to communicate with your device, probably integrated into OS Shell. At least 2 layes will be , if not 3 or more.

For eg windows xp you can make a virtual graphic card(and intercept  various things), for Vista not, just with a trick :)

It is very-very OS specific.